# how to access subview control in UITapGesture in objective- c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Hello Friends Please help me,
I have added UITapGesture on UIWindow but i can't able access parent control in screen

```
UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rot =[[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRotation:)];

 rot.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
rot.delegate = self;
 UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch =[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
 action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
 pinch.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
pinch.delegate = self;
/* UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
 action:@selector(handlePan:)];
 pan.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
pan.delegate = self;*/


//circle gesture
gr = [[MDCircleGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
[gr addTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
//[self.view  addGestureRecognizer:gr];
//gr.delegate = (id<MDCircleGestureFailureDelegate>)self.view;
gr.delegate = self;
gr.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

////Z gesture
cg = [[CharGesture alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(zLetterMade:)];
cg.delegate=self;
cg.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
//Add on window - RR
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window].gestureRecognizers = @[gr,cg,pinch,rot];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please confirm that you have given `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and enable interaction      `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window].userInteractionEnabled=YES;`